# Load different modules under the same url id

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, url-routing, ngrx

I have an URL `...steps/<step-id>...` and under this URL different modules can be loaded based on type field of object retrived based on step-id.

The issue is probably caused by race condition, because at first I'm retriving the object with required type in selector with the getRouterState usage.

And based on that I can run module:

```
 stepsMapper = {
        'ModuleA': async () => (await import ('@app/web/modules')).ModuleA,
        'ModuleB': async () => (await import ('@app/web/modules')).ModuleB,
        'ModuleC': async () => (await import ('@app/web/modules')).ModuleD,
 };
```

And run this like this:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: ROUTES,
            useFactory: routesFactory,
            deps: [ StepsFacade ],
            multi: true,

        },
    ],
    declarations: [ StepsComponent ],
})
export class StepsModule {
}

function routesFactory (stepsFacade: StepsFacade) {

    return {
        path: '',
        component: StepsComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: ':id',
                loadChildren: stepsFacade.getVal(),
            },
        ],
    };
}
```

and

```
getVal () {
     return this.stepsMapper[this.typeThatsNeedToBeLoaded];
}
```

Do you know how to bypass this race condition or is there better solution for this issue? Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is in what you supply as `loadChildren` value. Angular actually compiles the code (before TS compilation, that is), and it requires that some things have very specific types. In this case it [`[m]ust be an arrow function of the following form...`](https://angular.io/api/router/LoadChildrenCallback). You still can achieve what you need, just use `import()` directly in a stub (or better say broker?) component instead of `loadChildren`.

Comment: Another thing to mention, you have same import in all 3 cases, so, basically you load same module every time (2nd and 3rd times it will be cached). I'm 99% sure tree shaking is not going to work in this case, and you won't get any benefit from your conditional loading.